# ground_truth = np.squeeze(np.asarray(true_labels))

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Please help me understand this line of code?

What do the `squeeze` and `asarray` function do?

In this approach k-means clustering with k=5, and random initialization has been fitted.

```
ground_truth = np.squeeze(np.asarray(true_labels))
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs for `np.squeeze`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Answer (score 3):

In future if you could, please include more example code specific to the issue to make it clearer what you want to achieve from your question. K-means clustering and random initalization don't explicitly tell us what the value of `true_labels`, but I'm guessing it a 1d array of category labels so I'll answer purely from the standpoint that you want to understand these things:

1. What `np.asarray()` is doing
2. What `np.squeeze()` is doing
3. What happens when you put them together.

---

Firstly, what `np.asarray()` does is that it converts acceptable input (such as a list or a tuple) into a numpy array. Example:

```
# List to Array
>> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>> print(np.asarray(list))
Output: [1 2 3 4 5 6]
# Produces an array of shape (6,)

# Tuple to Array
>> tuple = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
>> print(np.asarray(tuple))
Output: [[1 2 3]
         [4 5 6]]
# This produces an array of shape (2, 3)
```

Now we move on to what `np.squeeze()` does. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html), it states that the function's description is to:

> Remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.

What this means is that if there are any redundant dimensions, they will be omitted from the output. Example:

```
>> x = np.array([[[0], [1], [2]]])
>> print(x)
Output: [[[0]
          [1]
          [2]]]

>> print(x.shape)
Output: (1, 3, 1)

>> print(np.squeeze(x))
Output: [0 1 2]

>> print(np.squeeze(x).shape)
Output: (3,)
```

---

Now with the above examples in mind, let us revisit the original expression `ground_truth = np.squeeze(np.asarray(true_labels))`.

1. Let's take the variable `true_labels` to be a list of numbers corresponding to categories.
2. `true_labels` is passed into `np.asarray`. A numpy 1d array is returned.
3. This numpy array is passed into np.squeeze which removes redundant dimensions if any are present (ie. from shape (6, 1) to shape (6,)).
4. The squeezed numpy array is assigned as the variable `ground_truth`

I hope this clarifies what is happening in that line for you.